# How is the best workaround to check if a user exists or not in RevenueCat using the API without creating new users

Tags: get, revenuecat, customer-account-data-api

I have a task to get subscriber info from each user in my database. However, some users exist in my database but are not subscribers. The point is RevenueCat offers only one endpoint to do both things (GET and POST). Check it on https://www.revenuecat.com/reference/subscribers.

Whether I request `https://api.revenuecat.com/v1/subscribers/{app_user_id}` and this `app_user_id` does not exist in my RevenueCat contacts base, RevenueCat creates a new user as it was a "free subscription" user.

This makes things harder since I already had thought to check that recent created user and delete it according to its attributes. But if it is a real "free subscription" user (an user with no subscriptions in my RevenueCat App) I would be deleting my real user from RevenueCat.

As seen on [Request all Revenue Cat customers with the REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76671336/request-all-revenue-cat-customers-with-the-rest-api), we do not have an "ETA" about when RevenueCat will offer a decent endpoint to get all customers base.

Other answers which do not helpd me, but it worths mention to avoid misunderstanding:

- [Check if Users Subscription is still active with the RevenueCat API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58581772/check-if-users-subscription-is-still-active-with-the-revenuecat-api)
- [Flutter/Revenuecat: Check if user has already bought something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72671612/flutter-revenuecat-check-if-user-has-already-bought-something)

What is the best workaround it would make sense to adopt here when you cannot request `https://api.revenuecat.com/v1/subscribers/{app_user_id}` before know that `app_user_id` actually exists in RevenueCat or not?

Comment: A "subscriber" in RevenueCat is the same thing as a "user" in your database e.g. it's anyone using the app it doesn't mean they have a subscription. RevenueCat has renamed this a "Customer" in their docs and other SDK objects but the REST endpoint still has the subscriber name. So I think what you're already doing sounds correct. Also, it could be worth exploring webhooks to keep things in sync vs pinging the API for every user in your DB.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was reading the RevenueCat's API doc and after some tests, I could figure out a simple way: when it creates an user, it returns 201 (created). Simply that!

Some docs require tests to understand them at full coverage. I may let this question and answer here to help others like me saving them time from tests.

Comment: Another trick I could confirm after a test is that we can check if attributs `request_date` and `first_seen` are equal and are the same as our request timestamp.